# Where does npm look for a package.json file?

Tags: node.js

I know `npm` looks for a `package.json` in the current directory, but it also appears to find a `package.json` several directories above my current directory.  How does this work?  Does `npm` look at parent directories until it finds a `package.json`?

If so, does `require()` also search for a `package.json` when looking for modules?

Is this behavior part of `npm` or is it part of CommonJS?

Answer (score 1):

`npm` doesn't really do much work w/ `package.json` except for all the heavy lifting of grabbing/resolving dependencies and putting them in the proper directory structure.  To the bet of my knowledge, npm does *not* inject its self a runtime dependency.

Node's `require()` performs the `package.json` resolution/parsing at runtime, as well as interaction with the `node_modules` directory.

Here's some pointers into the code that does that:

- [package.json resolution](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L94)
- [node_modules resolution](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L205)
- [the meat of package resolution](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L274)

Comment: Am I missing something? How does this answer the question?